# Concatenate variables in an UPDATE using SQLCMD

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I am tyring to use Concat in a query in SQLCMD, to no avail.

What would be atlernatives to :

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd `
    -Database $database `
    -ServerInstance $server `
    -username $dbusername `
    -password $dbpassword `
    -Query "UPDATE $table SET $x=Concat($x, $y) where id=$id"
```

I get:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: what is $x and $y? Do you just want to combine the two strings?

Comment: I agree with @MartinBrandl, please explain what you are trying to accomplish and not just the error you get from your attempt.

Comment: $x is a nullable string and so is $y

Comment: Basically $x comes from the table and $y from a file and I have to concatenate both.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to combine the strings yourself:

```
if (-not $x)
{
    $x = [string]::Empty
}

if (-not $y)
{
    $y = [string]::Empty
}

Invoke-Sqlcmd `
    -Database $database `
    -ServerInstance $server `
    -username $dbusername `
    -password $dbpassword `
    -Query "UPDATE $table SET $x=$($x + $y) where id=$id"
```